# Loop though Array of Objects and access specific key/value fields

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, key-value

I have an object that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Job Title",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "department": "Department",
    "id": 123456789,
    "name": "First Last"
  }
]
```

How do I loop through this object and save the value of email in a variable?

Here is my code:

```java
List<T> results = type.getResults();
String userEmail = "";

for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    if (results.get(i).equals("email")) {
        System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&& in IF condition &&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
    }
    System.out.println(results.get(i));
}
```

But I just can't seem to get this loop to work.

Comment: That looks like normal JSON.  Have you tried using a parser such as gson or jackson?

Comment: Is that not a JSON object?

Comment: Yes, I get this object from an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jackson-core and jackson-databind libraries.
Create a mapping object as below:

```
class User {
    @JsonProperty
    String id;
    @JsonProperty
    String title;
    @JsonProperty
    String email;
    @JsonProperty
    String department;
    @JsonProperty
    String name;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

Map the object as array as shown below:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        User[] users=objectMapper.readValue("[ { \"title\": \"Job Title\", \"email\": \"email@email.com\", \"department\": \"Department\", \"id\": 123456789, \"name\": \"First Last\" } ]", User[].class);
        System.out.println(users[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this json string to `List.class` and then use *typecasting* for inner objects:

```java
String json = "[{" +
        "\"title\": \"Job Title\"," +
        "\"email\": \"email@email.com\"," +
        "\"department\": \"Department\"," +
        "\"id\": 123456789," +
        "\"name\": \"First Last\"" +
        "}]";

List list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, List.class);

Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(0);

Object email = map.get("email");
Object id = map.get("id");

System.out.println("email: " + email + ", id: " + id);
// email: email@email.com, id: 123456789
```